# Conditions on a mySQL database entry

Tags: mysql, jsp

I'm working on an application in which a JSP page takes information filled out on a form and inserts them into a table in MySQL.

```
 My table :

 +-------- +-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
 | Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default    | Extra |
 +-------- +-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
 |UserID   | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI |            |       |
 |ino      | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | 0          |       |
 |epno     | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | 0          |       |
 |startDate| date        | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 |       |
 |enddate  | date        | NO   |     |            |       |
 |dist     | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL       |       |
 |cost     | int(6)      | YES  |     | NULL       |       |
 +---------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
```

I need each user's StartDate and EndDate period to be unique.
Also, none of the entries should overlap.

Eg. If userOne enters the following entry

```
        StartDate- April 30,2014 , EndDate:May 5, 2014
```

and there exists an entry in the table:

```
         StartDate- May 2,2014 , EndDate:May 6, 2014
```

It should not be allowed.

I have only specified multiple primary keys so far. I can change them if they are of no use.

Please feel free to ask any questions about the problem. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce this constraint with a `BEFORE INSERT` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html):

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM   my_table
  WHERE  StartDate <= NEW.EndDate
     AND EndDate   >= NEW.StartDate
  LIMIT  1
) THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET    MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Period overlaps with existing record';
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I tried this. It says 'You have an error in your SQL Syntax'.
I think this is not supported by my version of MYSQL (5.2).

Can you suggest some other way I could work this out?

Comment: @user3270763: You are correct, [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html) was introduced in MySQL v5.5.  As an alternative, you can simply perform some operation that raises an error, e.g. call an non-existent procedure e.g. `CALL raise_error;`.